# How to increase microphone level?

Tags: root-access, audio, microphone, volume

I just installed a custom ROM and everything is working fine except my microphone is very quiet in audio recording and voice messages.
Works fine on calls.

I've read on XDA that it can be fixed by editing mixer_paths.xml but I don't know which strings to edit.

Any help appreciated.